# Troubleshooting Wake-on-Lan on Dell Microplex

Tags: networking, boot, automation, wake-on-lan

I am trying to get WOL working, but it simply does not help to power on my devices. Here's what I have tried:

I have a 2 PCs of different make/models connected to a Cisco Switch. Both them do not work, so it's not something to do with a specific NIC, BIOS setting etc. So, I will focus the troubleshooting from 1 PC - which is of Dell Microplex that is running Proxmox.

- I am attempting local WOL. Not over the Internet. No port forwarding etc needed.
- I have checked the BIOS settings for this. Here are the screenshots (sorry for the poor quality, I will mention details in the description for easy readability)

[image]

BIOS > Power options > Enable USB Power Share, Enable USB Wake Support

[image]

Active State Power Management AUTO

[image]

Block Sleep OFF

[image]

Deep Sleep Control Disabled

[image]

Wake on LAN/WLAN -> LAN Only

- On Proxmox, here's the configured setting

[image]

- Here's the IP link settings from the proxmox shell

[image]
[image]
[image]

- I can confirm that the switch is not blocking any traffic because I captured traffic by generating a WOL packet from my Mac and I could see that it was received on the NIC. Here's a screenshot of that.

[image]

- I also tried directly connecting my Mac to the Dell server to send the WOL packet, but that didn't work either.

What else have I missed troubleshooting here? I cannot get WOL working despite checking all the possibilities. As mentioned, it affects 2 machines of different makes/models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*USB* power configuration isn't relevant. Internal NICs are connectec via PCIe, so you need to configure PCIe power management, something along *Power On by PCIe*, *Power on by PME*, or even *Wake on LAN*.

Some NIC drivers deactivate WoL on system shutdown, so you might want to unplug and replug mains power for testing. A very good indicator is when the NIC link/activity LED is lit or flickers with a soft-off system, especially when the switch indicates a reduced-speed link rate (10 or 100 Mbit/s).

Various sleep/standby modes deactivate WoL altogether, so it often only works from soft off.

Of course, you need a reliable tool for crafting magic packets for WoL. Always use the default hardware MAC address, no manually configured address (as far as I have seen).

Addresses that you configure on a hypervisor are not relevant for powering up the host. Some hypervisors support WoL though, so when the host is already running and accepting WoL magic packets to power up a specific VM.

Comment: The NIC link/activity LED definitely is not lit when I power off my machine. I believe this is a problem. What sleep state should the machine be on for WOL to work and any suggestion where I'd modify this? I also believe this has something to do with the switch. It's a cisco switch, do you have any suggestions on what should I change on the switch cli.

Comment: Try unplugging mains. If the NIC LED lights up when restoring power (w/o powering on), the driver or its config is the problem. WoL often only works in soft off (S5 state). The switch isn't relevant, it just needs to link in any speed (Auto Negotiation on, the right thing in any case).

Comment: Okay here's some progress. I do believe the switch is at play here. I connected the machine directly to my Mac. The NIC led was blinking and when I sent the magic packet, the machine did power on this time. So, it's definitely the switch. What do you suggest I check on the switch? thank you!

Comment: The switch just needs to support linking at 10 and 100 Mbit/s (depending on NIC). Check with the WoL speed with the other machine and temporarily configure it with the same speed, half duplex and see if the switch links. Perhaps it's a Gigabit-only port?

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. The problem was that I had forcefully set the speed to 1000. I configured auto for both speed and duplex and it worked. Thank you very much!